# How to watch movies compressed into .bin and .cue?

Tags: video, mount, binary

I have had some old VHS digitalized into DVD and used Window's PowerISO software to back them up in my external hdd. The I've got 4 videos that I want to run on Ubuntu 11.10:

- A.bin
- B.bin
- C.bin
- C.cue
- D.bin
- D.cue

How do I watch the video contents inside of those files?

Comment: Have you run them in VLC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accordinq to [this blog](http://theos.in/windows-vista/howto-play-bin-movie-dvd-file/), you can use VLC to watch your .bin videos.

From a more general point of view, VLC is famous for supporting nearly all the existing formats in video and audio.

Answer (score 0):

Try mounting the images (bin/cue) and then running through VLC.

Comment: How do I mount bin/cue?

Comment: Here you can have more details on doing that https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManageDiscImages

Comment: This does not provide a sufficient answer to the question. Try to add more information, and / or examples.